# Convert seconds to Minutes:Seconds in label MacOS

Tags: swift, xcode, timer, countdown, seconds

I am a school teacher and we have been 'ordered' to use a specific timer for our lessons, which low and behold doesn't work on our apple iMac's. I am trying to create my own in xcode and so far have created a basic window which will countdown a label in seconds. I have at the moment assigned the buttons and they work (in increments of 60 seconds).

[image]

This works and is fine but ideally i would like the label to display minutes and seconds instead (much easier for the kids). What is the best way to code this? Last time i used xcode was in 2009 and i am way out of date now!! Thanks in advance

--

```
    @objc func updateTimer() {

    seconds -= 1     //This will decrement(count down)the seconds.
    countdownLabel.stringValue = "\(seconds)" //This will update the label.
}
```

--

```
    @objc func runTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector:(#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

--

```
    @IBAction func threeMin(_ sender: Any) {
    seconds = 180
    runTimer()
}
```

--

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. More people will see your question if you add a primary language tag. (Is this Swift? If so, just [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51217883/edit) and e.g. add the `swift` tag in the tags box at the bottom.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add images rather as images than as links. This time I've done this for you - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice, i tried the image but it would allow me due to reputation points. Thanks for sorting it

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions. A convenient one is `DateComponentsFormatter`

```
let formatter : DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
    return formatter
}()

@objc func updateTimer() {
    seconds -= 1    
    countdownLabel.stringValue = formatter.string(from: TimeInterval(seconds))!
}
```

---

Some improvements:

Assign tags to all buttons with their value in seconds for example set the tag of the `threeMin` button to 180. Then use only **one** `IBAction` and connect all buttons to that action.

In the action first check if the timer is running and start it only if it's not running

```
var timer : Timer?

@IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: NSButton) {
   if timer == nil {
      seconds = sender.tag
      timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

   } 
}
```

Create a function to stop the timer reliably

```
func stopTimer() {
    if timer != nil {
       timer?.invalidate()
       timer = nil
     }
}
```

In the `updateTimer()` function stop the timer if `seconds` is 0

```
@objc func updateTimer() {
    seconds -= 1    
    countdownLabel.stringValue = formatter.string(from: TimeInterval(seconds))!
    if seconds == 0 { stopTimer() }
}
```